# Invalid Address error after setting defaultAccount

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment

I am trying to run contracts on a fresh Geth installation of a private blockchain network. It is working fine in the sense that I can transfer ether between accounts. But if I try to execute a contract, the JS Web3 file gets loaded, I set the defaultAccount as `web3.eth.defaultAccount = eth.accounts[0]` , unlock the account and then after getting the mined address, call the class. But when I call a function, it simply returns

> Error: invalid address
>
> at web3.js:3879:15
>
> at web3.js:3683:22
>
> at web3.js:4948:28
>
> at map (native code)
>
> at web3.js:4947:12
>
> at web3.js:4973:18
>
> at web3.js:4998:23
>
> at web3.js:4026:22
>
> at apply (native code)
>
> at web3.js:4151:12

For example, even if I execute a contract as simple as the greeter contract, greeter.greet() returns the above.

I assume that there must be a problem with my private network, but can't figure out what it is.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

I want this to run only on the private network, please refrain from suggesting trying it on public test network.